# How to redirect the Magento 2 controller into post page

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, redirect, post

When I click on add to cart button from my custom page.

If products are avaiable it goes to the Cart page and if not they are redirected to the Post page, but it redirects to the Index page.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by post page? custom page, you mean you create it on a custom module?

Comment: Can you please add your custom code?